# в чём ошибка я понимаю это максимально тупой вопрос

Tags: python, python-3.x

показывает ошибку в том что if не известен но это в онлине компиляторе но идле показывает на двоеточие

```
time = 0
        if 0 <= time < 6:
                print("Goog night")
        elif 6<=time<13:
                print(" Good morning")
        elif 13<=time<17:
                print("Good day")
        else:
            print("Good evening")
```

Comment: а че иф со смещением то?  а не сразу под таймом?

Comment: отформатируйте пожалуйста ваш код, смещение - имеет значение.

Comment: он все рано выдает ошибку 1 табуляцая там или две

Comment: Ошибка многих новичков, большинство языков программирования не поддерживают конструкции вида `6 <= time < 13`. Например, если `6 <= time`, то эта часть примет значение `True`. Далее вы получите `True < 13`, что всегда возвращает `True` (так как `True` из первой части интерпретируется как *1*) То есть это выражение будет истинно любого `6 <= time`, даже если оно больше *13*. И, как сказали выше, поправьте отступы

Comment: @Стас "большинство языков программирования не поддерживают конструкции вида 6 <= time < 13" - но Python как раз один из языков, который поддерживает такие конструкции

Comment: @insolor да? Вот этого я не знал, большое спасибо)

Comment: @TrinCars А должно быть ни одной табуляции, судя по всему

Comment: @ там уже показали как надо

Answer (score 4):

вот так попробуйте:

```
time = 0

if 0 <= time < 6:
    print("Goog night")
elif 6 <= time < 13:
    print(" Good morning")
elif 13 <= time < 17:
    print("Good day")
else:
    print("Good evening")
```

дело в том, что в питоне важны отступы, отступ показывает некоторый блок кода, относящегося в строчке кода выше

ваш `if` обязательно должен был быть под `time = 0` без каких-либо отступов иначе питон не понимал как этот `if` и код выше надо обрабатывать

Comment: И всё же код нужно пояснять по правилам, если он не самоочевиден. А для автора вопроса, похоже, не очевидно в чём дело )